# How to use Grep to find the number of matches from one file to another

Tags: grep

I am trying to find the amount of times a match occurs from a list of patterns given in the pattern file, to the target file.  Here are example target and pattern files:

Target File

```
are
bare
barely
be
beware
care
clever
```

Pattern File

```
be
are
```

I know that I can do

```
grep -F -c -f patternFile targetFile
```

to get the number of strings that have one or more match in the pattern file in them, but I want to count the total number of matches.

Here is where grep is not returning what I really want:  In the example above `beware` is matched by both `are` and `be` and should count as two matches, but is only counted as one match by the grep statement above.

Comment: It doesnt have to be with grep if someone knows another quick way to do this from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a one-liner, this small Perl script does the job:

**Code:**

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# check for 2 files given as argument
my $f1 = shift @ARGV or die "missing file 1";
my $f2 = shift @ARGV or die "missing file 2";

# load all words to search
open my $fh1, '<', 'file1.txt' or die "$!";
my @wrd = <$fh1>;
chomp @wrd;
# loop on the fiile to be searched
open my $fh2, '<', 'file2.txt' or die "$!";
my $count;
while(my $line = <$fh2>) {
   $count += $line =~ /$_/ for @wrd;
}
say "$count occurrence of ", join' or ',@wrd;
```

**Files:**

```
cat file1.txt 
be
are

cat file2.txt 
are
bare
barely
be
beware
care
clever
```

**Usage:**

```
./test.pl file1.txt file2.txt 
7 occurrence of be or are
```