# How to group and count all lines in a file that contain specific string

Tags: grep, sed, awk, aggregation

I want to filter all lines from a file that contain `mySearchString` and after that group them together and count them.

Example find all lines that contain `9791`

```
AB-9791___Foo
AB-9791___Foo
DE-9791___Bar
AB-0001___Foo
```

Using  `$ grep "9791" myFile.txt` gives this result

```
AB-9791___Foo
AB-9791___Foo
DE-9791___Bar 
// 0001 was filtered out
```

This result should be grouped and counted (like SQL `Group by Count`) like this

```
AB-9791___Foo     2
DE-9791___BAR     1
```

This [answer uses perl](https://superuser.com/questions/1526435) but perl is not installed on our machines.

What tool is usefull ( [grep](/questions/tagged/grep), [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), or other) to achieve the second part to group and count?

### Update with test records

In my test file `Test_2.txt` these lines are written

```
AB-9791___Foo
DE-9791___Bar
AB-0001___Foo
AB-9791___Foo
AB-9791___Foo
AB-9791___Foo
DE-9791___Bar
DE-9791___Bar
DE-9791___Bar
```

I copy und pasted each `AB-9791___Foo` line so they should be identical.
Running `$ grep '9791' Test_grep_uniq_sort.txt | uniq -c` gave this result

```
  1     AB-9791___Foo
  1     DE-9791___Bar // expected: 4 actual: 1, 2, 1
  3     AB-9791___Foo // expected: 4 actual: 1, 3
  2     DE-9791___Bar
  1     DE-9791___Bar
```

Running `$ sort Test_2.txt > Test_2_sort_0.txt` and then using `grep | uniq` on `Test_2_sort_0.txt` did almost return the expected output.

```
  $ grep '9791' Test_2_sort_0.txt | uniq -c
  4     AB-9791___Foo
  1     DE-9791___Bar // this is due to a missing line break / line feed
  3     DE-9791___Bar
```

After adding a line break / line feed by hand everything did work

Comment: Simple curiosity, what OS are you using?

Comment: I am on windows 10 but have a bash under windows available. AFAIK this includes the [coreutils pdf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#uniq-invocation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have to `sort` the file before.**

You can use `grep` and `uniq` like this:

```sh
 grep '9791' file1 | uniq -c
      2 AB-9791___Foo
      1 DE-9791___Bar
```

Comment: Thanks it did work after i figured out that the file has to be sorted first: `$ sort -c Test.txt > file1` and then `grep '9791' file1 | uniq -c`

Comment: @surfmuggle: True, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to grep for either A or B (`9791` or `9891` ) for example `grep '9791|9891' file1`  <-- but this does not work.

Comment: @surfmuggle: Escape the pipe: `9791\|9891`

Answer (score 1):

`uniq -c` for count and `awk` for swap columns:

```bash
$ uniq -c <<END | awk '{print $2 " " $1;}'
AB-9791___Foo
AB-9791___Foo
DE-9791___Bar
END

AB-9791___Foo 2
DE-9791___Bar 1
```

A few ideas is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627014/count-number-of-similar-lines-in-a-file

Comment: You need to `grep` before. They only want lines that contain a pattern.